# Silverlight Global Mouse Down Event Handler

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am desperately trying to implement a "Session Inactivity Timeout" for an IT security policy.
sss
However, my inactivity reset logic isn't firing.  What am I doing wrong?  I can't attach a breakpoint due to Visual Studio crashing on attaching to Silverlight binary.  I am wondering if the problem is something very subtle, such as at the time the App constructor is called, there is no "current RootVisual" yet. Tagging with #WPF as well since #Silverlight is dead/obsolescent.  Sample code below.

```
namespace TestApp
{
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer sessionTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    public App()
    {
      ResetSessionTimer();

      this.RootVisual.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(rootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
      //this.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown += rootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown;
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ResetSessionTimer()
    {
      sessionTimer.Stop();
      sessionTimer.Tick -= sessionTimer_Tick;
      sessionTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
      sessionTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
      sessionTimer.Tick += sessionTimer_Tick;
      sessionTimer.Start();
    }

    private void sessionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("LogoutButton").Invoke("click", null);
    }

    private void rootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      // added this alert to see if code is even firing.
      System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("alert", "hello, world");
      ResetSessionTimer();
      e.Handled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - somewhere in the code, the previous developer was overriding the this.RootVisual element with a new MainPage() in order to enable their homegrown dependency injection / MVVM architecture.  I moved the logic from the App() constructor to right after this assignment operator, and it works like magic.